# How do you load typescript modules from node_modules using browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, tsify

When I run `tsc`, everything runs perfectly fine. However, I cannot understand how you are meant to import other typescript modules from node modules.

This is the important part of my gulp file:

```
gulp.task('compile-ts', ['clean'], function(){
  var sourceTsFiles = [
    config.allTs,
    config.typings
  ];

  var bundler = browserify({
    basedir : "src",
    debug : true})
    .add("app.ts")
  //.add("typings/tsd.d.ts")
  .plugin(tsify);

  return bundler.bundle()
        .pipe(source("bundle.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write({includeContent: false, sourceRoot: 'src'}));

});
```

When I use,

```
import {DataRepository, List} from "tsmvc";
```

Where `tsmvc` is a typescript module node module, I get `cannot find module tsmvc.` Atom doesn't complain and shows me intellisense, tsc doesn't complain, but tsify does.
Can anyone point me to a gulp file doing something similar or explain the process?

Here's the github repo: https://github.com/Davste93/typescript-mvc-consumer/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: Seems to be the issue described here: https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify/issues/60 - can't understand what the resolution was there though.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to version 0.15.3 of `tsify`, it was not possible to import TypeScript files from within `node_modules`.

Internally, the `tsify` plugin creates a transform and Browserify does not transform files under `node_modules` for non-global transforms. In version 0.15.3 of `tsify`, the `global` option was added and can be specified as follows:

```
var bundler = browserify({
    basedir: "src",
    debug: true
})
.add("app.ts")
.plugin(tsify, { global: true });
```